# How can I install the RDCOMEvent and SWinTypeLibs packages in R?

Tags: excel, r, installation, package

I've been trying to run some code using the `RDCOMClient`, `SWinTypeLibs` and `RDCOMServer` packages for R.

The code can be found at the following address: 
http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMEvents/examples/excelButton.R.

Unfortunately, when I try to load either the `SWinTypeLibs` or the `RDCOMServer` packages, I get the following errors:

> "Error: package 'SWinTypeLibs' was built before R 2.10.0: please
>   re-install it"
>
> "Error: package 'RDCOMServer' was built before R 2.10.0: please
>   re-install it"

The version of R I was currently working on was R 2.13.2. I have then tried using an earlier version of R to remedy to this problem (version R 2.9.2).

This solved the problem for `SWinTypeLibs` but I got the following error for `RDCOMServer`:

```
Error in .cacheClass(cl, cldef, is(cldef, "ClassUnionRepresentation"),  : 
  trying to get slot "package" from an object (class "classRepresentation") that is not an S4 object 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: '.__M__createCOMObject:RDCOMServer' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
2: '.__M__getValueOf:RDCOMServer' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
3: '.__M__QueryInterface:RDCOMServer' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
4: '.__M__setValueOf:RDCOMServer' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
5: 'createCOMObject' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
6: 'getValueOf' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
7: 'QueryInterface' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
8: 'setValueOf' looks like a pre-2.4.0 S4 object: please recreate it 
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'RDCOMServer'
```

Note that before this I have also installed both the `SWinRegistry` and `Ruuid` packages that are required packages for `RDCOMServer`.

Does anyone know what I could do to solve this problem?

Comment: Install the latest version from http://rcom.univie.ac.at/